# Android and SQLite interactions: updating row with multiple intents

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a program with a main activity which spawns 4 different intents with lists in each. There is a database used to track all of the choices from these lists. Currently with the way that `startActivityForResult()` works I am having the program send back a comma delimited string which is saved in an array in the main activity and upon main 'submit' it is all saved to the database. The lists represent choices made on a per-day basis but each list corresponds to the same day. I am using `putExtra()` to send the correct list to the activity.

This can be an issue if the user closes the program or android kills the app the array may be lost.  I want to update the current dates data from each spawned intent but when I would do this it would create a new entry.

**Main question:** Can I set a global date  value (that the user sets in main) that each intent can reference to use `update` for my sql statements.  I want to make sure that there is no loss in data.  Currently writing to the database is only done in the main activity upon submit but I would like to have the app write to the db from each intent.

This question is very abstract in my brain and if there is a need to clarify I will do my best. (I am at school and just brain storming things to try when I get home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the array to Shared Preferences in onPause() and onTerminate().  You can use the array element number as the key and whatever is in that array element as the value.

I can't quite work out where you're going with the global date/time stamp, but if the point is to prevent data loss, Shared Prefs can be damned handy.